# SQL Server - Reduce number of Reads

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I have one general question about optimization at SQL Server: How I can reduce number of Reads in stored procedure?

I'm interested in good practices like: 
- creating indexes at physical and temp tables
- using temp tables instead using same table couple times in procedure
- DDL before DML
- SET NOCOUNT ON at the beginning of stored procedure
- ...

We have issue with disk space that is used because of huge number of reads that is caused by couple stored procedures and I need to optimize it.

Part of stored procedure that is 'the most expensive' is:

```
create table #stavke   
(  
    Id_Br int identity(1, 1), IDStavke int, 
    HeaderID int, Currency varchar(3),  GLAcct varchar(20), id varchar(20), Trnuid varchar(60), 
    ReferenceID varchar(20), DocumentID varchar(20),
    DtAvail varchar(10), DtBooking varchar(10), DatePosted varchar(10),
    Amount money, AmountLcl money, 
    Description varchar(250), Type varchar(10), DP int  )
insert into #stavke   
  (  
    IDStavke, HeaderID, GLAcct, Currency, id , Trnuid , 
    ReferenceID, DocumentID ,
    DtAvail , DtBooking , DatePosted,
    Amount , AmountLcl , 
    Description , Type , DP 
  )  

SELECT S.ID as IDStavke,
   z.RB as HeaderID,  
   z.KONTO AS GLAcct,
   z.OZNVAL AS Currency,
   Si.BROJNALOGA as ID,
   D.TRN as Trnuid, 
   case substring(SI.BROJNALOGA,1,4)
        when '0746' then O.REFERENCA
        when '1450' then D.REFERENCA
        when '0743' then L.REFERENCA
        when '2021' then N.REFERENCA
   end   ReferenceID,
   case substring(SI.BROJNALOGA,1,4)
        when '3000' then 'Kursna razlika'
        when '2200' then 'PP-'+SI.BROJNALOGA
        when '2201' then 'KDP-'+SI.BROJNALOGA
        else SI.BROJNALOGA
   end DocumentID,
   dvalute as DtAvail, 
   si.dknizenja as DtBooking, 
   '' as DatePosted,        
   case si.teret
        when 0 then si.korist
        else si.teret 
   end Amount, 
   case SI.DINTERET
        when 0 then si.dinkorist
        else si.dinteret 
   end AmountLcl, 
   '' as Description,
   case substring(SI.BROJNALOGA,1,4)
        when '0746' then '0746'
        when '1450' then '1450'
        when '0743' then '0743'
        when '2021' then  'Ostalo'
   end  Type,
   case SI.DINTERET
        when 0 then 1
        else -1 
   end DP
FROM       A I
inner join B st on i.transfer=st.transfer and i.partija=st.partija 
INNER JOIN C SI ON st.RB=Si.RB
inner join D z on z.rb=st.rb
inner join E s on z.rb=s.rb AND s.BROJNALOGA = si.BROJNALOGA 
LEFT JOIN  F D ON  D.BROJ=SI.BROJNALOGA
LEFT JOIN  G L ON L.BROJ=SI.BROJNALOGA
LEFT JOIN  H O ON O.BROJ=SI.BROJNALOGA
LEFT JOIN  I N ON N.BROJ=SI.BROJNALOGA 
WHERE I.novi_izvod=convert(int,@StatementNumber) AND i.PARTIJA=@Account 
ORDER BY I.PARTIJA,z.RB,SI.id, z.KONTO,z.OZNVAL, SI.DKNIZENJA
```

Tables B, G, H and I (I changed real names of tables for this example to make it easier for reading) are very big, i.e. have many columns and big amount of data.

Comment: How are **READS** causing disk space issues in your environment?

Comment: That's a very broad question and one that many large books have been devoted to. You may be better off asking a more specific question (how can I optimize X) and provide code and schema.

Comment: I agree you need to ask specific question here.  If you have a couple problem stored procedures then post them and ask how to optimize.

Comment: I would migrate this to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ but in it's current form this question is just too vague.

Comment: I edited post in that way that added part of stored procedure that is 'the most expensive' and that needs to be changed. Also, I would suggest to administrators to give more time for post editing before close it, because I have seen your answers too late probably because of different time zones...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you are talking of minimizing the disk activity by a procedure.

firstly, you can benchmark your current IO activity using the

```
set statistics IO on;
```

With that info at hand and getting the Execution Plan with SET SHOWPLAN_ALL or XML or you can make use of ssms to get the same ergonomically. You can make use of DTA for basic tuning.

Try executing the SP as a bunch of ad-hoc statements and see where the IO is heavy and concentrate on that segment. There are a lot of good practices which might suit your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I optimized stored procedure in that way and got very good results! As first I used SET STATISTICS IO ON; and in Execution Plan have seen which parts of procedure are consuming the most resources. After that used Database Engine Tuning Advisor and created indexes in accordance with recommendations that I got. Also got recommendations to create STATISTICS and some tables that could improve performances. At MSDN I found suggestions to accept recommendations from DETA for creating STATISTICS.